# Why does using [element].click() on the client bypasses router in Next.JS?

Tags: next.js, next-router, next-link

We have a React application using Next.js. My understanding is NextLink works by adding a click event to the element, stopping normal navigation and letting the router handle it instead. For example:

```
<Link href="/app/page">
  <a id="my-link">Go here</a>
</Link>
```

This sends up being rendered as an `<a>` tag with a click and onClick event. When the user click the link, the event uses `preventDefault()` and then handles navigation. Without using NextLink, the router would not be used and navigation would reload the application/state/etc.

So we wanted to manipulate our UI programmatically with a script loaded with the browser dev tools for testing purposes. We noticed that if you do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("my-link").click()
```

The Next router is effectively bypassed. Why is that the case? Shouldn't triggering the click event like this be the same as the user clicking an element?